# setTimeout runs faster on iPad vs PC

Tags: javascript, ios

I'm creating an HTML5 web app meant for the iPad, but which can also be run in a PC browser.  I'm using the javascript function setTimeout to synchronize some screen transitions with an audio file playing in the background.

Specifically, the code I'm using is:

```
setTimeout(showStartScreen, 30000);
setTimeout(showInstructionScreen, 60000);
```

On a PC the timing is perfect and the transition matches up with the audio fine.  On an iPad 2, the transition is about a half second faster than on the PC.  ON an iPad 3, the transition is even faster.

Is there a more reliable way to time something across different platforms?

Comment: can you split your audio file in to pieces?

Comment: no, in iOS5 I need a user interaction to play each file, so to get around that I chained them together into one file

Comment: Or make use of a player that can return you the current position of the playing audio, if you are not using that already

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than creating a timeout and hoping that the timer keeps in sync, you should poll the audio's `currentTime` and act on it.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var now = audio.currentTime;
    // do something based on the audio's position.
},25);
```

This assumes you are using HTML5 `<audio>` elements.